# Can I 'symlink' product categories?

Tags: category

I realize my answer may be [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/how-to-avoid-duplicate-categories) but I thought I'd post the question just in case anyone knows. I have a very dense category structure and I want to avoid duplication. Ex:

```
Category A
 +-- Category C (unique)
 +-- Category D (contains 90 products)
Category B
 +-- Category E (unique)
 +-- Category F (same 90 products as D)
```

In this way I might have 10 more categories with the exact same content as D and F. How can I get categories D and F to originate from the same place in the admin panel? i.e. if I make a change to D, I want that change reflected in F too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to duplicate a categories product set without re-assigning all the products to the new category then OnTap's Visual Merchandiser module allows you to do this with Smart Category Rules.

The link to the module can be found at http://www.ontapgroup.com/visual-merchandiser.html (Note this module is included by default on Magento Enterprise Edition)

Once installed you can go to the Visual Merchandiser tab and create a new Smart Category rule, all you need to do it select `Clone Category ID(s)` and input the ID of the category you want to take the product range from.